# Good agnostic template system for Rails and JS (server/client) or client-side templating for JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, template-engine

I have a request about choosing template engine, reusable both in Rails and JS, probably only server (node.js) or client side one, but if it would work for both - it is better of course.

Could anyone suggest nice, maintained system, which utilizes normal rails approach (partials, collections render), and works well with JS as well. Also, how it should be configured, assuming Rails normally use instance variables with @ sign, which isn't valid for JS. I see haml interpreter for Node.js (not sure how compatible with normal haml is it).

Another possibility is templates only in JS part, with Rails maintains only data, which rises question about tools for this way - what libraries except bacbone should be checked?

Comment: what about mustache or handlebars?

Comment: do you actually want to reuse the _same_ templates both in JS & Ruby ?

Comment: Mustache has no logic, and no partials as far as I see. Handlebars looks like JS-only engine. @mexique - yes, if this is possible. Otherwise any template engine that would act nice with both languages is good.

Comment: Looks like there is handlebars.rb https://github.com/cowboyd/handlebars.rb

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template engine for Ruby and Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873691/template-engine-for-ruby-and-javascript)